# Where's this park in Yokohama, in Ep. 31 of "Terrace House: Boys & Girls in the City"?

Tags: japan, identify-this

I first stumbled on this screenshot on [Reddit](https://redd.it/a3o8qg),  from Episode 31 of  "Terrace House: Boys & Girls in the City". But I can't spot it  in [this map created by a fan](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=13T6nXZcJkK49AZAjj-34wfrNr_c&ll=35.11472882438712%2C144.7772890996555&z=5).

[image]

Comment: Got a screenshot of it in daylight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [Cup Noodle Museum Park](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Cup+Noodle+Museum+Park/@35.4557245,139.6395954,206m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m8!1m2!2m1!1samusement+park!3m4!1s0x60185c5a3bd93f75:0x91874608b5b84cc1!8m2!3d35.4561!4d139.6391454).

The arrow is exactly where they were standing in the show.

[image]